# get the list of all root dependent devices

Tags: 12.04, root

How do I get the list of all devices which are root dependent i.e either mounted on root filesystem or created from root devices(Logical volume on the top of physical volume which is root device).

### EDIT

Answer must be an script (may be shell) that will return list of all the root dependent devices.I dont wanna use any LVM specific package command (such as lvdisplay etc).

### 23-OCT-2013

As answer posted by @Oli,

```
mount | awk '$3 ==  "/" {printf $1}' | sed s'/.$//'
```

Only lists the device.But I want which of its partition is actually a root dependent.

I tried getting which LVM device is mapped to physical device using `dmsetup deps`

I got

```
ubuntu-swap_1: 1 dependencies   : (8, 5) 
ubuntu-root: 1 dependencies : (8, 5)
```

Above gives me mapping(can get by comparing `(major, minor)` number) but how can I ensure LVM is root device?

Comment: Why no `lvdisplay`?

Comment: @Oli use of `lvdisplay` will make it lvm package dependent. You need to install LVM package before using it(as its not inbuild). So no to `LVM` package commands.Can use `dmsetup` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- `df -h` will list all devices/mounts.
- `lsof /` will list all open files under root.
- `lvs`, `lvscan`, and `lvdisplay` are used for LVM information.

Comment: `df -h` will not give me `LVM` details which is created from root device. And I want devices which are either created from root or root device.

Comment: For LVM, you can use `lvscan`, `lvs`, and `lvdisplay`.

Answer (score 0):

Well to find out the root device (virtual or physical), I've been using:

```
mount | awk '$3 ==  "/" {printf $1}' | sed s'/.$//'
```

Past there, it's fairly simple. You either have a device, or you have a mapped device. If it's mapped, `dmsetup info` can help resolve physical devices:

```
$ ROOTDEV=$(mount | awk '$3 ==  "/" {printf $1}' | sed s'/.$//')
$ sudo dmsetup info -Co blkdevs_used $ROOTDEV | tail -n+2
sdg,sdf
```

Of course, if `$ROOTDEV` isn't a mapped, device, everything will explode in a sticky, hot mess. It should be noted that dm-mapper can map partitions, so you may need to recurse through returned devices until you end up with `sd*` strings.

I've no idea how this works in an LVM environment. I've tested it on JBOD and dmraid-1.

Comment: Thanks for replying.But your solution wont work in case of `LVM` devices.I am testing it on `ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: Can you provide any actual output? You've tied our hands from using LVM specific tools so it's a bit hard to debug.